# Why does Python ignore SIGINT when started with & from a shell script?

Tags: python, signals

While debugging another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440353/python-time-sleep1-raises-typeerror), I discovered that if Python is launched from a shell script with `&`, the signal handling settings for SIGINT are changed to ignore it.

`x.py` contents:

```
import signal
print(signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT))
```

`noproblem.sh` contents:

```
python3 x.py
```

`problem.sh` contents:

```
python3 x.py &
```

When running `x.py` directly, directly with `&`, or through `noproblem.sh`, the signal handler for SIGINT is the default `signal.default_int_handler`, which is responsible for raising KeyboardInterrupt:

```
07:14 ~ $ python3 x.py
<built-in function default_int_handler>
07:14 ~ $ python3 x.py &
[1] 126909
07:14 ~ $ <built-in function default_int_handler>

[1]+  Done                    python3 x.py
07:14 ~ $ bash noproblem.sh
<built-in function default_int_handler>
```

But running `x.py` through `problem.sh`, SIGINT is ignored:

```
07:14 ~ $ bash problem.sh
07:14 ~ $ Handlers.SIG_IGN
```

I couldn't find any documentation explaining why this might happen. The [`signal` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) doesn't mention this behavior. Is this deliberate, or a bug?

Comment: The`&` in shell sends the new process created for the task to the background. Background processes do not receive signals.

Comment: @MYousefi: Background processes are fully capable of receiving signals, though they may not receive the same signals in the same circumstances as a foreground process. Note that your explanation would not explain why manually running `python3 x.py &` shows the default handler, or why any of this would affect Python's own signal handling settings if it were just a matter of whether signals are received.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974189/) can help.

Answer (score 1):

After further digging, I've managed to track down the cause.

First, if Python inherits an OS-level setting of SIG_IGN for SIGINT from its parent process, it does not install its default SIGINT handler. It only installs that handler if it inherits a SIG_DFL setting. We can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Modules/signalmodule.c#L1425-L1448) for the `signal` module:

```c
IntHandler = PyDict_GetItemString(d, "default_int_handler");
if (!IntHandler)
    goto finally;
Py_INCREF(IntHandler);

_Py_atomic_store_relaxed(&Handlers[0].tripped, 0);
for (i = 1; i < NSIG; i++) {
    void (*t)(int);
    t = PyOS_getsig(i);
    _Py_atomic_store_relaxed(&Handlers[i].tripped, 0);
    if (t == SIG_DFL)
        Handlers[i].func = DefaultHandler;
    else if (t == SIG_IGN)
        Handlers[i].func = IgnoreHandler;
    else
        Handlers[i].func = Py_None; /* None of our business */
    Py_INCREF(Handlers[i].func);
}
if (Handlers[SIGINT].func == DefaultHandler) {
    /* Install default int handler */
    Py_INCREF(IntHandler);
    Py_SETREF(Handlers[SIGINT].func, IntHandler);
    PyOS_setsig(SIGINT, signal_handler);
}
```

Second, shell scripts run with job control disabled by default, and processes started with `&` when job control is disabled inherit SIG_IGN settings for SIGINT and SIGQUIT. Quoting [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11):

> If job control is disabled (see the description of set -m) when the shell executes an asynchronous list, the commands in the list shall inherit from the shell a signal action of ignored (SIG_IGN) for the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals.

I could not find an explicit standard quote saying job control is disabled by default in shell scripts, only [quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) saying job control is enabled by default for interactive shells (vaguely implying the opposite setting for noninteractive shells):

> -m

> This option shall be supported if the implementation supports the User Portability Utilities option. All jobs shall be run in their own process groups. Immediately before the shell issues a prompt after completion of the background job, a message reporting the exit status of the background job shall be written to standard error. If a foreground job stops, the shell shall write a message to standard error to that effect, formatted as described by the jobs utility. In addition, if a job changes status other than exiting (for example, if it stops for input or output or is stopped by a SIGSTOP signal), the shell shall write a similar message immediately prior to writing the next prompt. **This option is enabled by default for interactive shells.**